# Trying to achieve a hasManyThrough type relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to achieve something that is similar to Laravel's `hasManyThrough`, but I'm not sure my DB is set up appropriately or I'm just missing something.

I am trying to display a page for admins to show all of the sites we support. I would like to have a simple column that shows a distinct count of how many customers are attached to each site. To do this, I was going to go through the `orders` table and retrieve a `distinct` list of users, then simply use the `->count()` method inside my view.

Here is my DB setup (simplified):

`sites` table (primary key: 'id'):

```
id | ...
```

`users` table (primary key: 'id'):

```
id | first_name | last_name | ...
```

`orders` table (primary key: 'order'):

```
id | order | user_id | site_id | ....
```

`Site` model:

```
public function customers()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\User', 'App\Order', 'site_id', ' id')->distinct();
}
```

I realize right away that the key difference between my DB setup and the documentation is I do not have an `order_id` in my `users` table, but it doesn't make sense that I do since a user can have many orders.

It is worth noting: I also have a table `user_orders`. I'm not sure if I should be using that instead. `user_orders` has the following set up:

```
id | user_id | order
```

You can see that it is simply an intermediate table to hold connections between users and orders (remember `order` is the PK in orders, not id).

So, can anyone help me understand what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why not select count from orders table and distinct by user_id and group by site_id?

Comment: That raises another question, how to I pair that query onto the collection I am passing my view? Because in my view I am looping over the collection to create table rows.

Comment: Don you need just the numbers? The DB query would return a array or something like that which you can loop.

Comment: Why do you have a user_orders table ? Can one order have multiple users ? You could try and do this : ```return $this->hasManyThrough(
           'App\Order', 'App\OrderUser',
            'order_id', 'user_id', 'id'
        );```.

Answer (score 0):

You could get away with a Join. I give you this sample code to guide you

```
public function customers()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Order')
    ->leftjoin('users', 'users.id', 'orders.user_id')
    ->groupBy('users.id'); //Is this needed?

    //Above code will return you a collection of Order though, but with the user data. 
    //Let's try using the User model 
    return App\User::whereHas('orders', function($query) use ($this->id) {
        $query->where('site_id', $this->id);
    })->get();
}
```